# Expo App works fine on development mode but crashes on productions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm currently developing a simple orders app which works ok on development, but if I install the apk from build or run the app on production mode through Expo Client I get this error:

```
TypeError: (0,f.useState) is not a function. (In '(0,f.useState)(!0)', '(0,f.useState)' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in C
    in B
    in RCTView
    in View
    in RCTView
    in View
    in RCTScrollView
    in y
    in ScrollView
    in w
    in P
    in RCTView
    in View
    in RCTView
    in View
    in RCTView
    in View
    in ForwardRef
    in RCTView
    in View
    in k
    in ForwardRef
    in PanGestureHandler
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in View
    in k
    in ForwardRef
    in RCTView
    in View
    in H
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in View
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in View
    in Unknown
    in w
    in b
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in View
    in x
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in O
    in P
    in RCTView
    in View
    in RCTView
    in View
    in O
    in RCTView
    in View
    in f
    in RCTView
    in View
    in AnimatedComponent(View)
    in RCTView
    in View
    in AnimatedComponent(View)
    in PanGestureHandler
    in le
    in L
    in O
    in P
    in R
    in O
    in O
    in l
    in c
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in View
    in RCTView
    in View
    in C
```

My current config is:

- expo-cli: 4.0.17
- expo-sdk: 40.0.1 (react-native 0.63.3)
- react: 16.13.1
- react-dom: 16.13.1

This error doesn't happen at startup but when I reach a particular page.
Things I tried so far after reading a lot of QA about `TypeError: (0,f.useState) is not a function`:

- reinstall node_modules, clear npm cache, delete watchers.
- use `React.useState` instead of `useState`.
- check for help on expo forums.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue? Or what can I try to make it work?
Regards!

Comment: are you using different babel transforms for your production build? you should use standard debugging techniques to try to isolate the specific code that is causing this problem. remove some code until the app runs successfully, even if this means bringing your app back to a "hello world" state. gradually add back code until it breaks again. then bisect the code you added back until you can narrow it down to a single line

Answer (score 6):

I run the app in prod mode without `--minify` arg `(expo start --no-dev)` and I was able to fix this issue.

Debugging I found autocomplete imported `useState` from another instance of React which caused this issue.

Hope this helps anybody with this or similar issues.